# Windows 7 64 bit errors

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk, windows-7-backup

I'm not the sharpest crayon in the box so forgive me if this is posted wrong.  Every couple of months I run the "chkdisk" function of Windows 7 and just discovered errors that when corrected crash my system.  The files wftplwf.sys, wimmount.sys, wmilib.sys and ws2ifsl.sys are deleted and my only recourse is the restore the only recent system image I have.

I've run from admin the cmd prompt and the "sfc /verifyonly" and the the error is too long to submit. A partial text file follows:

2013-02-17 15:52:46, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
Repair transaction
2013-02-18 18:01:34, Info                  CSI    000003fb Repair results created:
POQ 174 starts:

POQ 174 ends.
2013-02-18 18:01:34, Info                  CSI    000003fc [SR] Verify complete

I guess I can live with a working system from the image restore file but just have a hope someone can help.  I don't want to reinstall Windows and some 20 critical programs.

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: If `chkdisk` is causing critical system files to be deleted then the intrigity of your hdd should be in question.  The simple answer is to address that problem before you address the `sfc` tool not working

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already done so, you want to run memory diagnostics on your system, as the SFC error you posted suggests RAM issues.
Windows provides a tool called the Memory Diagnostics Tool.
Here are directions to get it started:

- Open the Start menu.
- In the Start Menu search box, type mdsched and press ENTER.
- Select the RESTART NOW AND CHECK FOR PROBLEMS option.

You can follow the prompts from there.
I'd suggest starting this at the end of your day with the computer, so it can run overnight.

Should this come back clean, I would suggest checking out your hard drive.
Your drive manufacturer will provide the best tools for determining if your drive is beginning to show signs of a mechanical or electronic failure. 
If you know your drive's original equipment manufacturer, consult their website to download a tool that will provide you with the ability to run tests.
If you do not know the name of your drive's original manufacturer, it can be determined by using device manager.

Here are directions to use Device Manager to find your drive information:

- Open the Start menu.
- In the Start Menu search box, type device manager and press ENTER.
- Expand Disk Drives
- Note the devices present

Once you see the list of devices you may see the drive manufacturer listed.
If you do not, simple type the text string associated with the drive into your favorite search engine. Information should come up that will identify the drive's make and model.
For instance, my hard drive's text string in Device Manager reads:
ST750LM022

When I plugged this into Google, the first and second hits are both entitled "Samsung SpinPoint".
Knowing this, I type the following into my favorite search engine: samsung hard drive disk test

And I wind up at this page: http://drive.seagate.com/content/samsung-en-us

At this point, by clicking **Support and Downloads** I am taken to a page that gives me a link to Samsung's SeaTools application. This application permits me to perform a variety of tests on my drive. In my professional experience, this tool catches 99.9% of failed drives.